# Java method to log into ASP.NET Web form

Tags: java, screen-scraping, httpurlconnection

I'm working on a java program that will need to log into a ASP.NET web form, then once authenticated, download a file.  Normal HTTP GET/POST is not a problem, but it appears that ASP is not giving me a SESSION ID when I connect from java, but it is from the browser.

When I look at the header information in Firefox, I see the cookies being set from the initial login, but then the page is immediately redirected over to a new URL.  I'm not sure if it matters, but the page it redirects to after login contains iframes.  I've tried loading both the main page and the iframe src inside, but neither give me the cookie in the header.

```
//Pull up the login page, extract out the hidden input variables __VIEWSTATE, __EVENTVALIDATION
URL url = new URL(loginPage);
HttpURLConnection conn = null;
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
//This reads the page line-by-line and extracts out all the values from hidden input fields
Map<String,String> formFields = getViewstate(conn);

//Now re-open the URL to actually submit the POST data
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();            
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setDoInput(true);
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
String postValues = URLEncoder.encode("txtUsername", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(uid, "UTF-8");
postValues += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("txtPassword", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(pwd, "UTF-8");
postValues += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("__EVENTTARGET", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("", "UTF-8");
postValues += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("__VIEWSTATE", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(formFields.get("viewstate"), "UTF-8");
postValues += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("__EVENTVALIDATION", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(formFields.get("eventvalidation"), "UTF-8");
out.writeBytes(postValues);
out.flush();
out.close();
//At this point looking at Firefox sniffer data, it should be sending back the cookie
//However there is no Set-Cookie in the header fields
for (int i = 1; (key = conn.getHeaderFieldKey(i)) != null; i++) {
        // get ASP.NET_SessionId from cookie
    if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("set-cookie")) {
        sessionId = conn.getHeaderField(key);
        sessionId = sessionId.substring(0, sessionId.indexOf(";"));
    }
}
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    //The page it prints out is the page it was redirected to when logged in through the browser
    System.out.println(line);
}
rd.close();
//At this point, it was a successful login, but I never got the cookie so I'm stuck
```

Answer (score 2):

HttpClient, which I believe HtmlUnit is based on, has the lower level functionality I think you're looking for. Handles cookies well, though if you need more, then Kurt is right in that you should look for something with more functionality. If you actually need to get full browser functionality, you could try something like Selenium/Webdriver that actually automates a browser under programmatic control.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the site you are trying to access relies on Cookies which are not supported by HttpURLConnection. A way around this issue is to use a library like [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) which simulates a browser (supports cookies, javascript, etc..).

Comment: I should be able to parse out the Headers to extract the cookies though, right?  I get all the standard headers returned, but no cookies.  Unless maybe I need to need to explicitly tell the server I accept cookies

Comment: That last is a good point, I think most servers have some mechanism for testing whether or not cookies are supported. I know Weblogic sets its session id in both the URL and a cookie on the first request, then on the next request it compares the URL value with the expected cookie, and if they match it drops the URL encoded id going forward. If you are getting the cookie, are you sending it back? Do you have follow redirects set to true? A higher level library is still probably your best bet to do what you want without tons of custom code.